# Unusual response when adding a minute to a calendar object

Tags: java, time

I wrote a function that creates a `Calendar` instance like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(startYear, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

I print the date in each row to the screen, and then add one minute:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
```

For all the years before 1999 it works fine, but when I try 1999 and it gets to `03/09/2016 01:59`, adding a minute causes it jump backwards to `03/09/2016 01:00`.

When I run the same script for 2016 it stops on `30/10/2016 1:59`, and when adding a minute it results in `30/10/2016 1:00`.

What could be going on here?

Comment: What timezone is your JVM running in; and do you mean September 3rd or March 9th? It looks like you're hitting the changeover of daylight savings time. But I'm surprised that is happening at the start of September or March.

Comment: I did not set the time zone, and September 3rd

Comment: Whether or not you set it explicitly, your JVM has a default timezone. Try running `System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());` to find out what it is.

Comment: In some countries you have a time change during the year, lilke in summer and winter. At the end of October is a good date to have time chage one hour less. So your Locale matter.

Comment: Yes This is the problem Thenks!